# popen() with sleep() call does not work

Tags: c, linux, unix

I have tested the below code to sort the strings.

Reason i added sleep to check, if sort program will wait on its read pipe for the information to sort. Below program works without sleep() call, why?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXSTRS 5

int main(void)
{
        int  cntr;
        FILE *pipe_fp;
        char *strings[MAXSTRS] = { "echo", "bravo", "alpha",
                                  "charlie", "delta"};

        /* Create one way pipe line with call to popen() */
        if (( pipe_fp = popen("sort", "w")) == NULL)
        {
                perror("popen");
                exit(1);
        }
        //printf("sleeping\n");
        //sleep(10);
        /* Processing loop */
        for(cntr=0; cntr<MAXSTRS; cntr++) {
                fputs(strings[cntr], pipe_fp);
                fputc('\n', pipe_fp);
        }

        /* Close the pipe */
        pclose(pipe_fp);

        return(0);
}
```

Comment: So what happens when you include the `sleep()`?

Comment: when i include sleep() call with printf("sleeping"),  i dont see the 'sleeping' statement printed. i am testing this code on http://www.compileonline.com/compile_c_online.php and i dont see the names of strings array. If i remove sleep() call then everything works fine.

Comment: That could be buffering. Try `fflush(stdout);` after your `printf` but before your `sleep()`.

Comment: i read in below link http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/69057/what-are-the-advantages-of-using-named-pipe-over-unnamed-pipe        that one reason namedpipes is used "you don't have to start the reading/writing processes at the same time" is this the reason? But if OS scheduler preempts the calling process then it is similar to sleep() call?

Comment: as per your suggestion, i placed fflush(stdout); between printf() and sleep() call, now i see "sleeping" as output, but what about those 5 strings

Comment: You are never going to see those strings.  `popen` is a one-way deal.  You can use the pipe to write or to read, not both.  Your sorted strings disappear at the end of sort.

Comment: what i understood from above program is calling process is working with write pipe opened and sort process with read pipe opened. and as read pipe is not receiving the data immediately due to sleep() call, may be sort process is killed? DO you think the same?

Comment: If i just cutpaste this above program, i see those 5 strings and why can't i see, and am using pipe as a one-way deal, where my calling process is writing and sort is reading?

Comment: Your `sleep`, in all honesty, is doing nothing.  You see the strings because `sort` is just writing them to stdout.  What I meant is that your C program will never see them as there is no mechanism (with popen) to write them back.

Comment: Yes i understand that, calling process is not receiving the sorted strings, But, sort process is writing strings to its stdout and if  sleep() is enabled in calling process, then i can't see the sort output?

Comment: Do I misunderstand sth here?  The question is "This is working (displaying the sorted strings) when there is no sleep, but why is it stopping to work (won't display the sorted strings anymore) when there is a `sleep` added to the code?"  Correct so far?

Comment: @Alfie, I dunno anymore.  Maybe.

Comment: @user3317808, the sleep is irrelevant.  It really doesn't do anything and should affect anything.  *Maybe* you had a buffering problem.  *Maybe* you just didn't wait 10 seconds before sort ever got something to sort and print out.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem.  Without the `sleep` this is working for me; with the `sleep` it is waiting for ten seconds and then also is working.

Comment: @Alfe,  Yes, you understood my question correctly.

Comment: as i dont have a linux machine, i tried this on   http://www.compileonline.com/compile_c_online.php

Comment: @Alfe, Does sort process exit() only after calling process sends \n character in the end after sending 5 strings? if that is the case then i need to find a machine to test this code.

Comment: That compileonline link is not this pgm.

Answer (score 0):

You probably are just running in a limitation of the site you are using to test your code.  With smaller values for the `sleep()` (e. g. 1) this works just fine.  I guess that the test site is applying timeouts to the programs it compiles and runs in order to have a decently reactive web site.

Get a decent unix and try it there; you probably will have as little trouble executing it as I did.

Comment: i also see string "sleeping" 3 times weirdly on this testing site? What do you mean, when you say: "in order to have a decently reactive web site"

Comment: The web site is meant to display the output of a program.  HTTP isn't originally meant for continuous output over a long time; it is meant for single question-answer mechanism (although today there are extensions to that).  So I understand what I observed in my tests:  That site seems to abort the given programs after a certain (rather short) timeout in order to give a timely answer to the request the browser sent.

Comment: If the site is killing the process it probably has to do with resource usage more than http.  Otherwise why not fork 100 processes and mine for bitcoins on their host?